# Android Studio: error while parsing signed release APK

Tags: java, android, proguard

I am working on an android app and everything works fine when I build it in my local system and run on emulator, but as soon as I make and release and install apk on my phone, it crashes with error -

```
There was an error parsing the package
```

As you can see, I am building with latest SDK and build tools, and my phone is running the same version on API too. I have Untrusted Sources installation allowed too and signed my app,

**build.gradle -**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'xxxxx'
            keyPassword 'xxxx'
            storeFile file('E:/Projects/Android/oiu.jks')
            storePassword 'xxxxx'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sd.edu.oiu.medicine.mustafa"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.1+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile project(':libs:MaterialDrawer')
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:itemanimators:0.2.4@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:crossfader:1.3.7@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:crossfadedrawerlayout:0.3.4@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.4.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:octicons-typeface:3.0.0.1@aar'
    // Charts
    compile 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.0.10-SNAPSHOT@aar'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="sd.edu.oiu.medicine.mustafa"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="24" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MaterialDrawerTheme.Light.DarkToolbar.TranslucentStatus"
        tools:replace="icon" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/login" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/register"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RestPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/reset_password"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityResults"
            android:label="@string/drawer_item_student_results" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivitySecondResults"
            android:label="@string/drawer_item_student_second_results" />
        <activity
            android:name=".StudentsList"
            android:label="@string/drawer_item_student_list" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RobotNoor"
            android:label="@string/robot_noor" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityFees"
            android:label="@string/drawer_item_student_fees" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/about_app" />
        <!-- adding our service -->
        <service android:name=".NotificationListener" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i even tried to make new empty android project and sign in and had the same error on release apk

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Comment: Suddenly the android studio start to sign apk apps correctly, I don't know how since I used alot of methods to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the build tools version to 24.0.0

Comment: could you give me the full error report from the android monitor

Comment: the build of the APK is successful but the problem is when i try to install it from android device if get this parsing error, how to get the error report from that ?

Comment: did you try a debug version on your real device?

Comment: the debug is working, but when i try to sign the app with a new key it give me this error

Comment: Did you follow the right instructions to build your signed apk follow these instructions https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html, I can't understand how you got the error while your device is not connected in your android studio right or you got the error on the mobile screen??